# FileSystemWatcher: Ignore changes made by own process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystemwatcher

I want to ask if there is a possibility to ignore changes within the
file system changed event made by the own process the FileSystemWatcher
is running in.
For example my own process creates a file in a watched directory and the
FileSystemWatcher should recognize that it was created by the process or
do not raise the event from the outset.

Comment: Your process knows it changed the file - so it should keep track of that in something like a `MemoryCache` with a short duration. Then the code using `FileSystemWatcher` can read from the `MemoryCache`.

Comment: Is it an option to _not_ create the file _in_ the watched directory?

Comment: Please explain the scenario more explicitly. What events do you subscribe to? And when a file is created by your application, should it be ignored forever by the FSW? Only for its Created event, or also for Modified/Deleted? Also consider that the FSW can miss events that happen in rapid succession, so  do you have a "backup loop" that scans files and checks whether they were picked up by the FSW, and if not, triggers for them to be processed?

Comment: I have a little sync app for files with my server. My problem is while an initial sync with lots of files it can happen that the consolidation time of five seconds will be exceeded and the synced files trigger a new sync. My plan was to ignore changes while the initial sync to avoid unnecessary syncs. After the initial sync they should not be ignored any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of files the application operates on:

```
static private readonly List<string> WatcherFilesToIgnore = new List<string>();
```

```
try
{
  WatcherFilesToIgnore.Add(filePath1);
  WatcherFilesToIgnore.Add(filePath2);
  // some file operation
}
finally
{
  WatcherFilesToIgnore.Remove(filePath1);
  WatcherFilesToIgnore.Remove(filePath2);
}
```

Hence in the watcher event handler you write at the beginning:

```
if ( WatcherFilesToIgnore.Contains(e.FullPath) ) return;
// watcher process
```

Thus when your application acts on some files, the watcher will do nothing for the specified to ignore.

If you use multithreading, consider using some synchronization.

---

As mentionned by @CodeCaster there may be a lag between the application and the windows shell event raised.

A simple thing could be to add a `Sleep(2000)` for example but it can be hazardous.

Thus we can use a `Dictionary<string, bool>` to indicate that the process is terminated and let the watcher clean itself the list:

```
WatcherFilesToIgnore.Add(filePath1, false);
// file operation
WatcherFilesToIgnore[filePath1] = true;
```

```
if ( WatcherFilesToIgnore.Contains(e.FullPath) ) 
{
  if ( WatcherFilesToIgnore[e.FullPath] )
    WatcherFilesToIgnore.Remove(e.FullPath);
  return;
}
// watcher process
```

This only work if a real watcher event is raised else the file will remain in the list.

So we need to ensure that in case of nothing is done we remove the file:

```
WatcherFilesToIgnore.Add(filePath1, false);

if ( ProcessFile(filePath1) )
  WatcherFilesToIgnore[filePath1] = true;
else
  WatcherFilesToIgnore.Remove(e.FullPath);
```

The `ProcessFile` method (I factored like that for the explanation) do the operation needed and returns true if some change successed, else false (nothing done, exception raised, process aborted...).

Comment: Is there a danger that the process alters File A, but this boolean results in other changes to File B (from other processes) being ignored?

Comment: Indeed... indeed. Answered too quickly. Thanks. Must add the filepath concerned.

Comment: OP needs to provide more details for this to be properly answered. The try..finally block is probably too short-scoped to exclude this file, FileSystemWatcher can have a delay. Event handlers also run on a separate thread, so you'll need to use a thread-safe collection.